# Does Ubuntu 18.04 lts support Intel uhd 770 graphic card? Is the driver integrated in the OS?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, intel-graphics, ubuntu-drivers

There is an industrial pc and was installed ubuntu 18.04 lts and a intel graphic uhd 770.But I found it showed 'llvmpipe' while I check the information of the device.
I can't change the resolution of my screen by clicking the botton.

Comment: Please be aware that Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, which was released in 2018-April (thus the 18.04) had 5 years of *standard* support life, is nearing the end of those five years. You can use `ubuntu-support-status` to confirm if your system is still *supported*. Either way, if the machine is on-line, you should plan to *release-upgrade* asap unless you plan to use ESM/Pro, but please note ESM/Pro releases are not on-topic here when standard support ends.

Comment: Online tools like https://packages.ubuntu.com/ no longer provide details for anything older than 20.04 as the five years of support for *bionic* or 18.04 ended last month, so our ability to help is even more limited now. We'd need to have a *bionic* system around (to do enquiries at terminal) or have *devscripts* installed that allow searching of ESM releases such as 18.04 (*18.04 ESM official start date is 31-May-2023 so you're on-topic on this site until then*).  I'd suggest planning your *release-upgrade* asap too.

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/05/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-begins-31-may-2023/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 18.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com//blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support